# Questions regarding direct proof for $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}~ k\cdot \ln\big(\frac{k+1}{k} \bigr) = n \ln(n) - \ln(n!)$

Tags: calculus, summation, proof-explanation, logarithms

I want to understand this direct proof for
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}~ k\cdot \ln\big(\frac{k+1}{k} \bigr) = n \ln(n) - \ln(n!)$$

[image]

$1.$ Why do we start with $k=2$ now and how do we get to $(k+1) \ln(k)$?

$2.$ Shouldn't that be a plus sign because we calculated $(k+1) \ln(k) = k \ln(k) + \ln(k)$?

EDIT: I have understood $3.$ now. It's because $\sum_{k=0}^n \ln(k) = \ln(1) + \ln(2) + ... + \ln(n) = \ln(1 \cdot 2 \cdot ... \cdot n) = \ln(n!)$

Comment: The equality right before label #1 is false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your Q.1, It is a typo. It should be

$$\sum_{k=2}^n  (k-1)\ln(k)$$

then your Q.2 is automatically resolved.

Answer (score 2):

The $k+1$ in the second line should instead be $k-1$.  It is a shift in summation index.  More generally, $$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} a_k = \sum_{k=2}^n a_{k-1}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$S=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k \ln\big(\frac{k+1}{k} \bigr) =\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k \ln(k+1)-k\ln k] =\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}( k+1-1) \ln(k+1)-k\ln k] =$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}( k+1-1) \ln(k+1)-k\ln k] =\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(k+1) \ln(k+1)-\ln(k+1)-k\ln k]$$ $$S= =\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(k+1)\ln(k+1)-k\ln k]-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \ln(k+1)=S_1-S_2$$
$S_1$ can be done by telescopic summation
$$S_1=[(2 \ln 2-1\ln 1)+(3\ln 3-2 \ln2)+(4\ln4-3\ln3)+..+(n-1)\ln(n-1)-(n-2)\ln(n-2)....+(n\ln n-(n-1) \ln(n-1)]=n\ln n$$
and
$$S_2=\ln \Pi_{k=1}^{n-1} (k+1)=\ln[2.3.4.....n]=\ln n!$$